# Redirect to the latest custom post type in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

On my Wordpress website, I am trying to create a link, http://url.com/episode/?latest that redirects to the latest "episode" (a custom post type). I have modified this code snippet to this:

```html
//* Link to Latest Episode
function wpa_latest_episode_redirect( $request ){
    if( isset( $_GET['latest'] ) ){

        $latest = new WP_Query( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'episode',
            'posts_per_page' => 1
        ) );
        if( $latest->have_posts() ){
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( $latest->post->ID ) );
            exit;
        }

    }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpa_latest_episode_redirect' );
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ''taxonomy'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'
```

Answer (score 0):

when i look at the [Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters), i think the bug is because 'taxonomy' should be a taxonomyname like

```
$latest = new WP_Query( array(
        'videos' => 'episode',
        'posts_per_page' => 1
    ) );
```

but its

> Deprecated since version 3.1 in favor of ‘tax_query‘

so you should use

```
$latest = new WP_Query( array(
        'tax_query' => array(
          'taxonomy' => 'episode'
         ),
        'posts_per_page' => 1
    ) );
```

However, since you say that "episode" is not a taxonomy but a custom post_type, maybe this will work for you:

```
$latest = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'episode',
        'posts_per_page' => 1
    ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that helped! I was able to use this, which worked because I apply categories to the custom post type:

```
//* Link to Latest in Category
function wpa_latest_in_category_redirect( $request ){
    if( isset( $_GET['latest'] )
        && isset( $request->query_vars['category_name'] ) ){

        $latest = new WP_Query( array(
            'category_name' => $request->query_vars['category_name'],
        'post_type'      => array( 'episode' ),
            'posts_per_page' => 1
        ) );
        if( $latest->have_posts() ){
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( $latest->post->ID ) );
            exit;
        }

    }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpa_latest_in_category_redirect' );
```